# Specifying input sources (instead of intermediates) as prerequisites to target in Makefile

Tags: makefile

After reading the first few chapters of [Managing Projects with GNU Make](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006105.do), I've come up with my first non-trivial Makefile

```
all: libTest.a

libTest.a : Test.o MWE.o Test.dlink.o MWE.dlink.o
    nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -lib -o $@ $^

%.a : %.dlink.o %.o
    nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -lib -o $@ $^

%.dlink.o : %.o
    nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -dlink -o $@ $<

%.o: %.cu
    nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -dc -o $@ -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.dlink.o
```

This Makefile works but I really don't like specifying the intermediate files `Test.o MWE.o Test.dlink.o MWE.dlink.o` as prerequisites to `libTest`. I'd rather specify the input files `Test.cu` and `MWE.cu` or better still the wildcard `%.u`.

Comment: You don't have to specify *any* prerequisites if you don't want to, it's just that Make can do a better job for you if you do. Do you have a clear idea of what you want this makefile to do?

Comment: @Beta Yes I have a clear idea of what I'd like to do. Please refer to ArturFX's answer as well as my following comments. I welcome your comments on how to get Make to specify prerequisites for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can prepare a command (or set of commands) to build `libTest.a` from `Test.cu` and `MWE.cu`, you can have just a rule:

```
libTest.a: Test.cu MWE.cu
    list
    of
    commands
    needed
    to
    build
    the
    library
```

but this is hardly a reasonable way of using `make`. What you have shown us in original question is a `make`-ish way of doing things. However if that's your whole `Makefile` the rule `%.a : %.dlink.o %.o` is superfluous here.

What you can do is to generate those prerequisites automatically:

```
SOURCES=Test.cu MWE.cu
libTest.a: $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.o) $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.dlink.o)
    nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -lib -o $@ $^
```

If you prefer to not add filenames manually to `SOURCES` but prefer to use all `*.cu` files available in current directory, replace the `SOURCES` assignment with:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cu)
```

Comment: `SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cu)` gives me a make error `Makefile:13: *** missing separator. Stop.`

Comment: What is in line 13? What is first non-empty line above line 13?

Comment: The first non-empty line *above* line 13 is `libTest.a: $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.o) $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.dlink.o)`. As you may recall this line is part of the original Makefile.

Comment: Please make sure you have tabs not spaces as indentations, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097193/error-in-make-command-makefile18-missing-separator-stop).

Comment: Indeed the probem was spaces instead of a tab. What is the name of the features `SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cu)` and `$(SOURCES:%.cu=%.o) $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.dlink.o)`. I'd like to read about them so I can understand what the makefile is doing and be in a position to maintain it. At the moment I don't understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: `$(something)` refers either to variable or to function. `$(wildcard)` is a function. `$(SOURCES)` is a variable. $(SOURCES:%.cu=%.o) is a short form of using `$(patsubst)` function. On Linux system you can run `info make` (or `pinfo make`). There is also [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) available.